# Need to implement an instant messaging for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, chat

I'm building an iOS app for my boss, and I have to implement a chat. the app will run on iOS for now but in the future it's gonna run on android too, so I need a cross-platform working solution. I will develop it in Swift, on Iphone only.
once you logged in by Facebook , Twitter or email you'll be able to send messages to other users logged in the app and online. you know, waze style.

I think I cannot use iMessage since the app could be developed for Android too. 
I'm trying to understand Jabber but I am totally new at it, but is it possible to make such a service in PHP?
Boss told me to look for a third party chat service, pay it and stop but I cannot find the right one.

could someone help me?

Comment: Do some research on how whatsapp works, this is a poor quality question not about programming but about asking for reference. [This](https://github.com/firebase/ios-swift-chat-example) is a nice starting point.

Comment: use `websocket` protocol for communication. it is supported by both, iOS and Android. there are many implementations you can use or you can write your own. server side can be done in various languages, including PHP. I would recommend:

 - [SocketRocket][1] for **iOS** client
 - [Autobahn][2] for **Android** client
 - [Ratchet][3] for backend in **PHP**

of course, you should google for other implementations that fits your needs the best.

  [1]: https://github.com/square/SocketRocket
  [2]: http://autobahn.ws
  [3]: http://socketo.me

Answer (score 2):

There is a really good new tool named **Layer** which does exactly what you are looking for.

[Layer](https://layer.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There are many chat services availabale for both android and ios

1:Scringo

2:Firebase

3:Quickblox

i have tried with quickblox and it is really fine, easy to implement and use http://quickblox.com/